# Alamofire Session configured same if instantiated?

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

I replaced **Alamofire** request methods from directly calling **Alamofire.request** to calling via instantiated **SessionManager**.

I did it to set custom **Timeout** value.

#### Before

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters)
```

#### After

```
// Make SessionManager with custom timeout value
struct APIManager {
  static let shared: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
    return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
  }()
}

// Calling request
APIManager.shared.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters)
```

I am wondering if the any configuration other than **timeoutIntervalForRequest** is exactly same.

Comment: When using your created session timeout takes more than 20 secs?

Comment: When you use `Alamofire.request` Alamofire uses the default session configuration by default, so to answer your question other than the `timeoutIntervalForRequest` all other properties of your custom session configuration and default one should be same as you are specifying `URLSessionConfiguration.default`